# How to remove the submit button from a specific Drupal webform

Tags: drupal, drupal-webform

I'd like to remove the submit button from a specific Drupal webform, is this possible and if so how do I do it?

I'd also like to remove the previous button if possible as well from the same form.

Comment: You might want to go and accept some of the answers to your questions...

Comment: sorry not sure what you mean? please elaborate?

Comment: Never mind I know what you mean now

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You'll need to target and alter that form with hook_form_alter() as indicated by @googletop

To unset the submit, something like this in a custom module would work:

```
<?php
function my_custom_module_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {

  if ($form_id == 'webform_client_form_130') {
    if ($thiscondition && $thatcondition){
      unset($form['actions']['submit']);
    }
  }
}
?>
```

Same for the "previous" button, you'll just need to find it in the form array

Answer (score 4):

1. Copy the file `webform-form.tpl.php`
2. Rename it `webform-form-{nid}.tpl.php` where nid equals your node ID
3. Edit - add just one line after `print drupal_render($form['submitted']);`, 

   add this line: `unset($form['actions']['submit']);`

It works for me.

Answer (score 1):

You can alter any form in drupal, using [`hook_form_alter`](http://api.drupal.org/api/function/hook_form_alter/6).

Answer (score 1):

If you'd like a quick fix for a prototype, etc then you could just hide the button in CSS.

```
.block-webform .form-actions {
visibility:hidden;
}
```

The invisible button will still take up a space, but you won't be able to see it.

Answer (score 0):

I used these simple php lines in the `webform-form.tpl.php` because creating a `webform-form-{nid}.tpl.php` or a `webform-form-[nid].tpl.php` (as specified in the template file) does NOT work.
So I simply used an if condition on `$nid` webform just to unset the submit button on specific webform nodes.

```
print drupal_render($form['submitted']);
$arrayWithoutSubmitButton = array( 29, 30, 31, 32);
if( in_array( $nid, $arrayWithoutSubmitButton)){
    unset($form['actions']['submit']);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for this and for me, Etno's solution worked: the others didn't work for some reason.

The only thing I would add to this is that the file mentioned is in "/sites/all/modules/webform/templates/webform-form.tpl.php" and NOT the file in "/drupal/sites/all/modules/webform/templates/webform-form.tpl.php" (if you have such a file) - it took me a while to figure that out :)